# Firebase Cloud Messaging Device Group Management via HTTP v1 auth

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm moving my FCM implementation from Legacy API to the new HTTP v1 api.

I've already created my service account with firebase-adminsdk

I've also managed to send push notifications using HTTP v1 to device group tokens using the new JWT auth tokens generated from the service account json.

My problem is I'm getting a 401 unauthorized error when managing device groups from the legacy API

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/device-group

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/notification
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization: Bearer ya29.ElqKBGN2Ri_Uz...HnS_uNreA
project_id:SENDER_ID

{
   "operation": "create",
   "notification_key_name": "appUser-Chris",
   "registration_ids": ["bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
                        "cR1rjyj4_Kc:APA91bGusqbypSuMdsh7jSNrW4nzsM...",
                        ... ]
```

From the documentation it shows that they are using new JWT tokens to authorize management of device groups instead of the old server keys. (Server keys are also going to be decommissioned next year). My question is what exactly am I missing here? How exactly do I use the new service account to manage device groups?

Tried using firebase-admin-sdk json to generate JWT token to use in the device group API. Returns 401

### Update

The details regarding FCM device groups can be found here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/device-group#creating_a_device_group

Here is an example Request and subsequent response showing the issue.

Request:

```
 POST /fcm/notification HTTP/1.1
 Host: fcm.googleapis.com
 Content-length: 194
 Project_id: XXXXREMOVEDXXXX
 Content-type: application/json
 Authorization: Bearer ya29.removed:removed
 {
     "operation": "create",
     "notification_key_name": "test-group",
     "registration_ids": ["devicetokenidhere1","devicetokenidhere2"]
 }
```

Response:

```
 HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
 Content-length: 147
 X-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
 Content-security-policy: frame-ancestors 'self'
 X-content-type-options: nosniff
 Transfer-encoding: chunked
 Expires: Wed, 28 Jun 2023 14:24:59 GMT
 Server: GSE
 -content-encoding: gzip
 Cache-control: private, max-age=0
 Date: Wed, 28 Jun 2023 14:24:59 GMT
 X-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
 Alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000
 Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
 <HTML>
 <HEAD>
 <TITLE>Unauthorized</TITLE>
 </HEAD>
 <BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
 <H1>Unauthorized</H1>
 <H2>Error 401</H2>
 </BODY>
 </HTML>
```

My initial thoughts were perhaps we have to change something in the Google Cloud credentials, however there are no issues when posting a message to any one specific token ID using "https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/myproject-id-here/messages:send". The 401 only occurs when trying to use a device group. Secondly I thought that now the Legacy version is being removed, perhaps they need to update the "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/notification" URL to v1 too?

Comment: any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I'm doing the same thing and I'm also getting a 401 (unauthorized) response when trying to create a new device group. This occurs both via the OAuth Playground and via the web app itself. Very annoying response with no explanation.

Comment: I've added a bounty and a test-case along with document references to help get the problem resolved

Comment: Same here. I verified that the access token has the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging` scope. Still get 401.

Comment: been scratching my head for the last 3 days on this issue.

Comment: I've opened a ticket with Firebase support, and after some back and forth, they are looking into to. Will update here with the outcome.

Comment: just wondering if someone figured out how to fix this

Comment: Firebase support asked for a reproducer project which I haven't had the chance to put together yet, maybe in a couple of days. Maybe you can also open tickets with them to escalate the issue.

Comment: Ok so Firebase support reproduced the issue and acknowledged that the Device Group Management API is missing support for OAuth tokens which contradicts their documentation. They have filed the bug internally and said to keep an eye on release notes and documentation, they will either implement support or fix the documentation. In the meantime we keep using static server key auth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the documentation has already been updated. We can now use http v1 authentication with the device group management api by adding this in the header

`access_token_auth: true`

Reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/device-group

Answer (score 0):

After testing numerous time trying to make it work. We solve the problem using the legacy implementation. The bearer token doesn't work for the endpoint so try using your server key like this just like the old legacy implementation.

Authorization: key=Server Key

Google might have not fully implement the v1 for the device groups yet that is why we get the Unauthorized response.

Comment: Yeah, but the issue is server keys if i understand correctly, will also be decommissioned next year. Infact that's my current setup and I wanted to move the jwt tokens to migrate everything to the new setup